# Apache Felix not able to access Postgres JDBC

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, osgi, apache-felix

I downloaded Postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc3.jar and put it in felix\bundle directory.

My program accesses Postgres table EMP and prints it. I am trying to do it in Felix OSGi server. There are two parts of my program:

1. Part-1 program which simply connects to Postgres JDBC driver and opens the database:

   package com.myprogram.myemp;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   import org.postgresql.Driver;

   public class ConnectPostgres {

   ```
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/scott";
   static final String UNAME = "postgres";
   static final String PWORD = "password";


   public void myMain() {
       Connection conn = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       Statement st = null;
       String JDBC_DRIVER = Driver.class.getName();

       try {
           Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, UNAME, PWORD);
           st = conn.createStatement();
           rs = st.executeQuery("select * from EMP");
           while (rs.next()) {
               System.out.println ("EMP Name:" + rs.getLong("EMPNO") + " " + rs.getString("ENAME") );
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               rs.close();
               st.close();
               conn.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Part-2 program is more like launches a bundle as a service provider:

   package com.myprogram.myemp;

   import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
   import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;

   public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

   ```
   @Override
   public void start(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {
       ConnectPostgres app = new ConnectPostgres();
       app.myMain();
   }

   @Override
   public void stop(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {
   }
   ```

   }

The requirement is:
Using database connection of a popular database like Postgres or SQLite, I should be able to publish EMP table as a Service on a OSGi compliant server Felix, Equinox.

**The error which I am getting in Felix 3.0 is:

### Unsatisfied requirement(s):

(&(package=org.postgresql))**

The driver is there, I placed it under bundle directory.

The problem as it seems to me:

1. Database connections using JDBC are not possible in OSGi. Can OSGi connect to Databases? The specification, wikis, examples all seem to be silent about. Without which all examples look like Celsius to Fahrenheit temperature conversion programs, of no real value to business. Please correct me if my understanding about OSGi is wrong.
2. What could be I am doing wrong? What is the other way I should try to connect to database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you believe that just putting a driver JAR in the `bundle` directory is sufficient to install that driver into the OSGi framework??

Comment: Regarding question one... of *course* OSGi can connect to databases. This isn't explicitly pointed out because it doesn't need to be. Rather, don't you think it would be very explicitly pointed out if OSGi couldn't connect to databases?

Comment: +1 for Neil, though it does seem intuitive to drop a JAR in the bundle directory and expect it to become a bundle. Not 100% sure on their setup but that could be the case if not for postgresql drivers not being "OSGI ready".

Comment: Another point... the question says you are using Felix 3.0. That is very old and you should upgrade to Felix 4.2 if possible (though it will not fix this particular issue).

Answer (score 3):

The Postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc3.jar JAR is probably not an OSGI bundle, so you can't just install it the way you have.

Check here:

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/PostgreSQL+Driver+Adapter

> The official Maven artifact postgresql:postgresql is a plain old JAR without OSGi manifest headers. You will have to wrap this on the fly using the Pax URL wrap: handler, or build your own bundle, adding an OSGi manifest. This gap is to be filled by the Pax Tipi project.

Comment: Sheena: Thanks for your link. But I used some other link: http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/21893960212/how-to-turn-a-jdbc-driver-jar-into-an-osgi-bundle-jar. It has been very helpful. A step-by-step instruction for converting jdbc driver to an osgi bundle. And the bundle has been accepted by Felix 4.2 and it has run my program. But  the results are another story. Thanks for now.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you posted your solution =)

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of [postgresql (9.4-1201-jdbc41)](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.postgresql%7Cpostgresql%7C9.4-1201-jdbc41%7Cjar) already is an OSGi bundle.

Servicemix bundles now contains a bundled version of the postgres driver. So ou can find the [postgres jdbc driver in the maven central repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles%22%20AND%20a:%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles.postgresql%22).

Comment: Christian since the versions get updated all the time and i dont assume that they are all OSGi is it safe to check for OSGi ready state by opening the Manifest file in the latest version and then looking for the required entries? Is there another way I can determine if it is OSgi ready?