# How can I install postgresqljdbc to work in Karaf OSGi?

Tags: osgi, karaf

I want to install org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41 in Karaf but I get errors. How can I resolve these errors? Strangely on Windows my Karaf doesn't have errors with this Postgres jdbc but on Ubuntu it has these errors. Any clues appreciated.

```
Install Kar feature social_importer.kar/1.0-SNAPSHOT
java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle    
mvn:org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41 in feature(s) 

T: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.postgresql.jdbc41 
[127]: Unable to resolve 127.0: missing requirement [127.0]
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa)


Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.postgresql.jdbc41 [127]: Unable 
to resolve 127.0: missing requirement [127.0] osgi.wiring.package;
(osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa)
```

This might be related [Apache Felix not able to access Postgres JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675483/apache-felix-not-able-to-access-postgres-jdbc)

---

```
karaf@root()> install -s wrap:mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41
Bundle IDs:
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to install bundle wrap:mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41
karaf@root()> install -s mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41
Bundle IDs:
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to install bundle mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41
karaf@root()>
```

---

I looked in the Karaf logs with log level of INFO.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/service/jdbc/DataSourceFactory
    at org.postgresql.osgi.PGBundleActivator.start(PGBundleActivator.java:32)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory not found by org.postgresql.jdbc41 [5328]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)[:1.8.0_25]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Provisioning Postgresql JDBC Driver to Karaf 4.0.1**

```
        __ __                  ____
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/

  Apache Karaf (4.0.1)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/0.7.0/xml/features
karaf@root()>feature:install  pax-jdbc-spec
karaf@root()>feature:install transaction
karaf@root()>bundle:install -s mvn:org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1200-jdbc41
karaf@root()> service:list org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory

[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = org.postgresql.Driver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.version = PostgreSQL 9.4 JDBC4.1 (build 1200)
 service.bundleid = 52
 service.id = 113
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 PostgreSQL JDBC Driver JDBC41 (52)
```

**Definining a Postgres Pool Datasource to Karaf 4.0.1**

Theory at: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config

```
karaf@root()>feature:install  pax-jdbc-config
karaf@root()>feature:install  pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2
```

Create file under *KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.datasource-companymanager.cfg*
where `companymanager` is the datasource name.

```
osgi.jdbc.driver.name=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver-pool-xa

serverName=localhost
databaseName=companymanager
portNumber=5432
user=postgres
password=admin
dataSourceName=companymanager
```

Voilá you are done, your datasource is exposed to OSGI registry ready to be used at your will:

```
karaf@root()> service:list javax.sql.DataSource
[javax.sql.DataSource]
----------------------
 databaseName = companymanager
 dataSourceName = companymanager
 felix.fileinstall.filename = file:/C:/apache-karaf-4.0.1/etc/org.ops4j.datasource-companymanager.cfg
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = PostgreSQL JDBC Driver-pool-xa
 osgi.jndi.service.name = companymanager
 password = admin
 portNumber = 5432
 serverName = localhost
 service.bundleid = 64
 service.factoryPid = org.ops4j.datasource
 service.id = 119
 service.pid = org.ops4j.datasource.3cad9abf-49be-4868-8940-1623481b1363
 service.scope = singleton
 user = postgres
Provided by :
 OPS4J Pax JDBC Config (64)
```

The next step will be perhaps set up JPA if you are interested, you can keep reading and get the full example code from: 
https://github.com/antoniomaria/karaf4-eclipselink-jpa

Answer (score 2):

Just tested with Karaf 4.0.0.M2:
OSGi compendium exports org.osgi.service.jdbc

```
        __ __                  ____      
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/      
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_        
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/        
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/         

  Apache Karaf (4.0.0.M2)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()> feature:install transaction
karaf@root()> install -s mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/5.0.0
Bundle ID: 51
karaf@root()> install -s wrap:mvn:org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-   jdbc41
Bundle ID: 52
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State  | Lvl | Version            | Name                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------
51 | Active |  80 | 5.0.0.201305092017 | osgi.cmpn                    
52 | Active |  80 | 9.4.0.build-1201   | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver JDBC41
karaf@root()>
```

Comment: install -s wrap:mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc4
Bundle IDs:
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
        Unable to install bundle wrap:mvn:postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc4
karaf@root()>

Comment: Sorry I think I misscopied  the version. Try this one 9.4-1201-jdbc41

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work, ... I'm really quite desperate

Comment: By the way, which version of Karaf are you using?

Comment: I have tested with Karaf 3.0.3:
```
karaf@root()> feature:install transaction
karaf@root()> install -s mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/5.0.0
Bundle ID: 67
karaf@root()> install -s wrap:mvn:org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1201-jdbc41
Bundle ID: 68
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State  | Lvl | Version            | Name                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------
67 | Active |  80 | 5.0.0.201305092017 | osgi.cmpn                    
68 | Active |  80 | 9.4.0.build-1201   | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver JDBC41
```

Comment: Sorry the code in my previous comment is a bit messy. Basically you need to install "transaction" feature, and the OSGi compendium (org.osgi/org.osgi/compendium/5.0.0) which exports: org.osgi.service.jdbc. I haven't tested with Karaf 4.x but it is working with Karaf 3.x

Comment: I have not tested what you wrote yet as I did a work-around due to my deadline of Friday (now Saturday), then I will test what you said next week and try to bring it back into my work.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Karaf DataSources (JDBC) is an optional enterprise feature. In order to install the postgresql, please use the following statements.

karaf@root()> feature:install jdbc

karaf@root()> install -s mvn:org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1203-jdbc42

the above solution was tested on Karaf 4.0.1